# Is there a way to make it so the NetworkManager instantiates the player preafabs when the scene switches?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im making a multiplayer game using Unity with Mirror and FizzySteamworks. And im having a problem that i cant figure out. So my NetworkManager is in my Main Menu scene and is moved to the next scene with DontDestroyOnLoad. My question is: Is there a way i can make it so when the scene changes and its the scene named "Game" the NetworkManager script instantiates the player prefabs?

I don't want the player prefabs to instantiate in the Main Menu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could register to the scene changed event.  [Active Scene Changed Event](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-activeSceneChanged.html)

Comment: And then why not simply only deactivate and activate them rather than not spawning them at all ;)